# IAPs on App Store Connect: For in-app-purchase review, what does it mean to upload binary?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect, in-app-purchase

I added several in-app purchases to my project on App Store Connect, and it rejected them saying `Please upload a new binary`. I don't know what `upload a new binary means`. I've uploaded builds to TestFlight, is that all they're asking for here? Do I just upload a new build to TestFlight, and then they'll review and (hopefully) approve the IAPs, or do I need to notify them somehow?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are just asking for you to upload a new build. A "binary" in this case means the app binary (an app build).

The new build must have the in-app purchase products actually available and visible for Apple's testers so that they can try out the purchase process in your app.

Comment: So to confirm, I don't need to do anything to notify them to test it? They're just asking me to upload the build to TestFlight and then they'll review it? There's a "Submit For Review" button at the top, should I click that?

Comment: Yes, remember to click that :-)

Comment: I thought that "Submit for Review" is what will push the build live though. Doesn't it? I 100% do not want it to go live, just to be submitted for review so that the IAPs get approved.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "Live" exactly... if you're talking about the App Store, you can set it to not release when it is approve, but require manual release. If you're talking about TestFlight - that's not really going "live" - it is only going out to testers. You can restrict which people will get access to the TestFlight build.

Comment: Sorry I don't really follow. Right now it's on TestFlight and invites were automatically sent to internal testers. If I go to the App Store tab instead of the TestFlight tab on appstoreconnect.apple.com, there's a "Submit for Review" button at the top right. In order for the Apple team to review and approve my IAPs, do you know if I need to click that button? Or is what I've done, submitting it to TestFlight, all I need to do?

Comment: Well... if you want Apple to approve this for TestFlight testing - submit it on the TestFlight tab. If you want Apple to approve this for App Store - submit it on the App Store tab. Remember that you need to set it to wait for developer approval instead of immediate release as per your previous wish.